# Laravel returns 404 to all files inside public/

Tags: laravel, permissions, apache2

I downloaded a project to work at home.
I managed to get it up and running, but after two days banging my head against the wall I cannot, for the life of me figure out the following error:

"GET
http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/site/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
Status
404
Not Found"

This happens on EVERY file in the public folder. The funny thing is, if I go to every asset('/public/site') call in the program and remove only /public, leaving asset('/site'), it works without any problems.

I ASSUME this is because the root folder of the file is /app/public AND the asset() is looking for /public/site, which basically returns a /app/public/public path, even though it doesn't show up in the GET header. Does this make any sense?

I tried forcing the ASSET_URL to be only '/'. If I do so, the files are apparently found but not loaded, giving the error "the connection used to get this resource was not safe" and returning nothing.
ANY help would be appreciated, I'm losing my mind.

Comment: the document root should be pointing to the public folder ... what is it currently set as?

Comment: It is currently set to the public folder. (Since I don't know how to check it, I tested it by creating a new php file, placing it on public, and accessing it through localhost/fliename.php, and found it.)

Comment: If you have xampp try pasting the project in htdocs and visit localhost/project/public

Comment: Does that work in Apache? I don't have xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much deliberation and research, I've realized that the Laravel version of the project I downloaded is extremely outdated, and the asset() function was very, very borky.

Changing every use of asset to Storage::url was arduous and annoying, but solved all the problems.

Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

`public` shouldn't be in the URL, since that's where the site will be served out of.

Currently, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` should be pointing to `public/index.php`.

If it is, you just need to omit `public` from your asset URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I took this project from a server so I could test out some things in the local folder (I'm a new employee of a very, very small team).
Since this won't be run in a server anymore and is just local, is it possible for me to simply elevate the root folder one level up? (root folder as app instead of public).
There are about 300 mentions of public in asset calls.

Comment: You could put a "public" folder inside the "public" folder... then you will have the path you desire.